# Pinging a static IP Address from Pi

Tags: ip, ip-address, ethernet

I was pinging a device with a fixed IP Address from my raspberry pi with this code:

```
response = os.system("ping -c 1" + hostname)
```

it was working until lately(probably after upgrading the pi) I am getting:

> network unreachable

or

> ip not available

eventhough the device is there. There is no problem with the hardware and I have set a static IP address on the pi by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

any help ?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: its on a pi, i am using Linux 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved by resetting the pi to its default settings.